# HTML setting default text on select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `select` element of the form:

```
<select id="test" name="test">
<option value="blah">Test1</option>
<option value="blah">Test2</option>
.
<option value="blah">Testn</option>
</select>
```

I want to display the text "Select a test" as default.
I know the way of doing this is to set a new option

```
<option selected="selected">Select a test</option>
```

at the top. But I'm looking for some other way where I don't have to use the  tag.
Is it possible through javascript (jQuery will also do)?

Comment: You can access options array and the prepend your options arreay with the new option Element.

Comment: Reason for not adding a new option element ?

Comment: The problem is that the value from this select is sent to multiple php scripts which is coded by someone else. He hasn't added checks for empty or null values and I would have to change a lot of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've done this with a dummy entry in the past...

**HTML**

```
<select id="test" name="test">
    <option value="0">Select an option...</option>
    <option value="blah">Test1</option>
    <option value="blah">Test2</option>
    <option value="blah">Test3</option>
    <option value="blah">Test4</option>
    <option value="blah">Test5</option>
</select>​
```

**Javascript**

```
​$("#test").on("change", function() {
    if ($(this).val() != "0") {
        $("option[value=0]", this).remove();
    }
});​​​​​​
```

Here's a working example on jsFiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/97Bqr/

The "Select an option" option is removed as soon as you select something else.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a plain js solution:

```
var selecttest = document.querySelector('#test');
selecttest.insertBefore(new Option('select a test'),selecttest.firstChild);
selecttest.selectedIndex = 0;
```